# Extract image URLs with a specific pattern with PHP preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to list all image URLs of a string with PHP preg_match_all.

The image patterns are as such:

```
1. //c1.site.com/5/2421/38306891313_ce7844189b_n.jpg
2. \/\/c2.site.com\/2421\/24574382628_9a2af39e82_h.jpg
```

I am able to extract up to the following result:

```
m/5/2421/38306891313_ce7844189b_n.jpg // 'm' seems to be the end of .com?
```

However I am not sure how to include the subdomain, domain and .com:

```
preg_match_all('/([-a-z0-9_\/:.])\/([-a-z0-9_\/:.])\/([-a-z0-9_\/:.]+\.(jpg))/i', $data, $matches);
foreach($matches[0] as $image){
echo $image.'<br/>';
}

preg_match_all('/([-a-z0-9_\/:.])\\/([-a-z0-9_\/:.])\\/([-a-z0-9_\/:.]+\.(jpg))/i', $data, $matches);
foreach($matches[0] as $image){
echo $image.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Better use [**`parse_url`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) instead.

Comment: You're only matching one character at the start of the regex: `preg_match_all('/([-a-z0-9_\/:.])\/...`. You need a `+`, as in `preg_match_all('/([-a-z0-9_\/:.]+)\/...`.

Comment: How strong does your validation actually need to be for your project? https://regex101.com/r/xS1V2e/1 or trim the leading forward slashes: https://regex101.com/r/xS1V2e/2  Always try to minimize capture groups in your patterns.  I guess I'd like to see your expect result in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `parse_url` instead:

```
<?php

$string = "//c1.site.com/5/2421/38306891313_ce7844189b_n.jpg";

print_r(parse_url($string));
?>
```

Which yields

```
Array
(
    [host] => c1.site.com
    [path] => /5/2421/38306891313_ce7844189b_n.jpg
)
```

Comment: This will only work if I have already extracted all the possible image URLs, but I need to find them first.